# Type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, type-mismatch

I am new to visual basic . I want to delete a record based on phone number . The program will ask the user to enter his number and will delete the record after matching the phone number  with the database . I tried doing so but it is giving me an error "Type mismatch in criteria expression".
I am using ms access 2007 and I have speciefied the data type of the phone column as Number . Here is my vb code . Please help me . It must be one of my silly mistakes . In the insert data module , I have specified the datatype as Long , before that I had specified it as Integer but the same error persists .

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form5
    Public Connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\AMEN\Documents\Railway.accdb"
    Public Conn As New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Form5_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Conn.ConnectionString = Connstring
        If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            Conn.Open()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim okToDelete As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to cancel your ticket?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

        If okToDelete = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Dim str As String
            str = "Delete from Table2 Where Phone = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, Conn)
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                Conn.Close()

                MsgBox("Your Ticket Cancelled Sucessfully ! ")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        ElseIf okToDelete = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If phone is a numeric field (wrong!!!) then you don't need the quotes around your textbox value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone numbers should be stored as strings not as numbers. 
But a part from this your query is wrong if your Phone field is numeric.
In that case you don't need quotes around the `TextBox1.Text`. This will treat your input as a string and this string cannot be used to search in a numeric field.

The best approach is to use a parameterized query where you could specifiy the datatype of the parameter passed
(I have assumed that you have created the field Phone as Long Number in Access)

```
If okToDelete = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

    ' Check if your user types really a number.
    Dim number As Integer
    if Not Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, number) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number!")
        return
    End If
    Dim str As String
    str = "Delete from Table2 Where Phone = @phone"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, Conn)
    Try
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", OleDbType.Integer).Value = number
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering !!! I changed the datatype of phone to String and it worked . Thank you very much !